Java Spring, Temp files are not deleting from system temp folder in the multipart file uplaod spring boot 2.7.1
I am using springboot 2.7.1 and uploading the Multipart file .
our application deals with huge number of files . i am reading the multipart file using byte[] = file.getBytes()
I could see lot of files are storing in the system temp location (c/user/appData/local/temp) with the prefix upload_xx_xxxx.
when the request rprocess is completed few files are deleting and few are not at all deleting this causing out of memory error and temp folder is filling up with in a minute
since am using byte[] to read the file there is no resource leak as per my knowledge
how to handle this situation.
I tried changing the byte[] to inputStream for reading the file but not working
any suggestion
